# How to get identifier for a softalyer orderItem

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

There are a few billing items for eg:  "categoryCode": "guest_disk1" or  "categoryCode": "gateway_resource_group". How can I identify to which parent server does this resource belong? or how do differentiate between 2 resources of same category. Just like we identify 2 servers using hostname. I don't want to use "id" as identifier. I tried using parentId and parent but I always get it null for all resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `“ParentId”` is null, please see the `resourceTableId` property, it will have the `item_id` that you  need (resourceTableId: A unique identifier for a SoftLayer Service that is associated to an invoice item . ref: [SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice_Item](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice_Item)),

For example when executing this request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems?objectFilter={   "nextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems": {     "orderItem": {       "order": {         "id": {           "operation": 5874669         }       }     }   } }&objectMask=mask[id,categoryCode, item, parentId,orderItem[item],invoiceItems[id,resourceTableId,categoryCode,description,billingItemId],children[parentId,categoryCode,orderItem[id,description,order.id]]]
Method: GET

Where `”5874669”` is the orderId
```

My response is:

```
[
  {
    "categoryCode": "guest_core",
    "id": 70751841,
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "categoryCode": "ram",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "8 GB",
          "id": 92196283,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "remote_management",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Reboot / Remote Console",
          "id": 92196285,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "port_speed",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks",
          "id": 92196287,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "public_port",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "100 Mbps Public Uplink",
          "id": 92196289,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "service_port",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "100 Mbps Private Uplink",
          "id": 92196291,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "bandwidth",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "0 GB Bandwidth",
          "id": 92196293,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "pri_ip_addresses",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "1 IP Address",
          "id": 92196295,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "guest_disk0",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "25 GB (SAN)",
          "id": 92196297,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "os",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr - Minimal Install (64 bit)",
          "id": 92196299,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "monitoring",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Host Ping",
          "id": 92196301,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "notification",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Email and Ticket",
          "id": 92196303,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "response",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Automated Notification",
          "id": 92196305,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "vpn_management",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account",
          "id": 92196307,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "categoryCode": "vulnerability_scanner",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting",
          "id": 92196309,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "invoiceItems": [
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 229216475,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 236371529,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 254309359,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 227147491,
        "resourceTableId": null
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 245530073,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 263996519,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 284422451,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 274920353,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      }
    ],
    "item": {
      "capacity": "4",
      "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
      "id": 859,
      "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
      "keyName": "GUEST_CORES_4",
      "softwareDescriptionId": null,
      "units": "CORE",
      "upgradeItemId": null,
      "itemCategory": {
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "id": 80,
        "name": "Computing Instance",
        "quantityLimit": 20
      },
      "totalPhysicalCoreCount": 4
    },
    "orderItem": {
      "categoryCode": "guest_core",
      "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
      "domainName": "mesos.maceacs.com",
      "hostName": "2-master-1712",
      "hourlyRecurringFee": "0",
      "id": 92196281,
      "itemId": 859,
      "itemPriceId": "52135",
      "laborAfterTaxAmount": "0",
      "laborFee": "0",
      "laborFeeTaxRate": "0",
      "laborTaxAmount": "0",
      "oneTimeAfterTaxAmount": "0",
      "oneTimeFee": "0",
      "oneTimeFeeTaxRate": "0",
      "oneTimeTaxAmount": "0",
      "parentId": null,
      "promoCodeId": null,
      "quantity": null,
      "recurringAfterTaxAmount": "0",
      "recurringFee": "0",
      "recurringTaxAmount": "0",
      "setupAfterTaxAmount": "0",
      "setupFee": "0",
      "setupFeeDeferralMonths": 12,
      "setupFeeTaxRate": "0",
      "setupTaxAmount": "0",
      "item": {
        "capacity": "4",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 859,
        "itemTaxCategoryId": 166,
        "keyName": "GUEST_CORES_4",
        "softwareDescriptionId": null,
        "units": "CORE",
        "upgradeItemId": null,
        "itemCategory": {
          "categoryCode": "guest_core",
          "id": 80,
          "name": "Computing Instance",
          "quantityLimit": 20
        },
        "totalPhysicalCoreCount": 4
      },
      "order": {
        "id": 5874669
      }
    }
  }
]
```

In this response displays all items associated to the orderId.

In this first part:

```
[
  {
    "categoryCode": "guest_core",
    "id": 70751841,
    "parentId": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "categoryCode": "ram",
        "parentId": 70751841,
        "orderItem": {
          "description": "8 GB",
          "id": 92196283,
          "order": {
            "id": 5874669
          }
        }
      },
      ....
```

We notice this `"categoryCode": "guest_core"` doesn’t have ‘parentId’ ("parentId": null). It means that this item is the parent of this order.

But how to identify the id of this item?

Well, in `invoiceItems` section there is a property called ‘resourceTableId’, this is the id of parent item. I mean: `"resourceTableId"= 13102629` is the `id` of my `Virtual Guest`

```
 "invoiceItems": [
      {
        "billingItemId": 70751841,
        "categoryCode": "guest_core",
        "description": "4 x 2.0 GHz Cores",
        "id": 229216475,
        "resourceTableId": 13102629
      },
```

In `Children section` will show the other items associated to my order, where we can notice that they have parentId = null.

Comment: I have guest disk `"categoryCode": "guest_disk1", "resourceTableId": 9906799` This id is supposed to be either a virtual guest's ID or a baremetal server id? I cannot find this id in getVirtualGuests or getHardware API. I don't think we can have an independent guest disk. It should be attached to either a bare metal server or a virtual guest.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. The ` "categoryCode": "guest_disk1", "resourceTableId": 9906799` means that this item is a `portable storage`(In theory all secondary disks are portable storage). This belongs to ` SoftLayer_Virtual_Disk_Image`. Please execute the following to confirm that id=9906799 is a portable storage: [SoftLayer_Virtual_Disk_Image::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Disk_Image/getObject). Regards.